# Deserializing JSON with invalid C# identifier in CANoe

Tags: c#, canoe

I am having an issue where I cannot deserialize the JSON I am receiving. Example JSON:

```
{
    "header": {
        "product-type" : "product/electronics"
    }
}
```

The object which should be parsed is named "product-type" and is an invalid C# identifier. Dealing with this in C# is easy enough. But the problem I am facing is dealing with this issue inside the CANoe software. Currently the way in which I am receiving this JSON is by creating an object with a MQTT binding and Serialization type of JSON. I am assigning it an user-defined datatype, which contains members with same identifiers as that of the expected JSON to be received.

Problem arises here as I have to declare a member's name as product-type and the hyphen here makes it invalid. Please do note this is inside the CANoe software and not in a standalone C# program.

Searching around, I see something called JsonProperty can be added before an identifier to *rename* a JSON name to any other identifier name. But I realize this is something which can be done only in C# as such an attribute is not available through the vCDL code.

I was thinking of using the Plain serialization option available. But reading through the help documentation in CANoe Vector shows this is just for serialization and not in deserialization.

Any kind of work around to receive the JSON data is appreciated. Do comment if any extra information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

For CANoe versions >= 16 SP3, there is a new vCDL attribute for the Serialization, which is called "SerializationAttributes::Name". This attribute can be used to specify a name for a struct member, which will be used in the JSON string as a key for this struct member.

In your case, you could define your struct data-types in your vCDL like this:

```
struct inner_struct{
[SerializationAttributes::Name="product-type"]
string product_type;
}

struct outer_struct{
inner_struct header;
}
```

which will then lead to the upper JSON in your text, if you serialize
a Distributed Object/DO member with the data type outer_struct.

Moreover, as an alternative, you can very well use the Plain serialization as you mentioned. It should work perfectly for deserialization. You can define a "string"-type (or "bytes"-type, Plain serialization only works for these two data types) DO member in your vCDL ( for example : [Serialization="Plain"] consumed data string myreceiver;). Then, you can use (e. g) a Nuget package like Newtonsoft JSON to deserialize your data in your C# application model. You can also use an application model written in Python to deserialize your JSON string, as Python has built-in JSON support I think.

If you want to work with or visualize certain members of the deserialized JSON string in the Graphics or Trace Window in CANoe, you can define internal DO members in your vCDL for that purpose (internal data string mytracewindowvisualizer; or internal data int mygraphicswindowvisualizer;) and update them with the corresponding JSON member data.

By the way, always feel free to write or call the Vector support which will help you in these kind of situations and if you have any question.